# Fetch returns [object Promise], not the value (more below)

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, dom

I'm using breaking bad API to fetch datas and a quote from a character.

After the user enters a name, getCharByName() returns an [object (data)].
Then renderCharacter() creates the content, appends it to the DOM.
Every argument is working, except the last one, getCharQuote(), where I use another link to fetch the character's quote.

**This is the code:**

```
search.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    getCharByName()
        .then(data => {
            renderCharacter(data.img, data.name, data.occupation, data.nickname, data.appearance, data.portrayed, getCharQuote(data.name));
        })
        .finally( () => {
            document.querySelector('.content').style.opacity = 1;
        });
})
```

**This is the problematic code probably, but not sure. The console.logs are working:**

```
function getCharQuote (name){
        let firstName, lastName;
        [firstName, lastName] = name.split(" ");

        return fetch(`https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/quote/random?author=${firstName}+${lastName}`)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        console.log(data)

                        const [quoteData] = data;

                        console.log(quoteData.quote); //here I get the quote from quoteData

                        return quoteData.quote
                    })
    }
```

appending to DOM:

```
function renderCharacter (img, name, occ, nick, seasons, port, quote){
    clearContent();
    let card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('container');
    card.innerHTML = `
    <img class = "profilePic" src = "${img}">
    <div class = "info">
        <div class = "data">
            <h1 class = "name">${name}</h1>
            <ul class = "list">
                <li><span>occupation</span> ${occ}</li>
                <li><span>nickname:</span> ${nick}</li>
                <li><span>appearance:</span> ${seasons}</li>
                <li><span>portrayed:</span> ${port}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class = "quotes">
            <ul class = "list">
                <li>${quote}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
    document.querySelector('.content').appendChild(card);
}
```

[image: Preview of the page:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use await before quote in li in renderCharacter function and remember about async.